# How to fix different results from a Chow Test and a CUSUM test to find structural breaks using R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm trying to identify the structural breaking point in a time series regression. I'm using a CHOW test and a CUSUM test but I'm getting two different answers and I cannot figure out why.

I understand that the bounds I set impact the result and therefore that the answer to the CUSUM test is not actually period 73, but rather 90 + 73 = 163. However, this still does not match the result of the CUSUM test below which is 409. I've tried to change the boundaries but the difference remains.

```
#To load the data

install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)

construc <- new.env();
getSymbols('DAUTONSA',src='FRED', env = construc);
data <- construc$DAUTONSA;


#Setting up Chow Test


fitted.values <- fitted(opt.model)
ARBreak <- matrix(fitted.values)

CTest <- ARBreak[1:626] 
for (i in 90:535){

  #Left
  yp1<-ARBreak[2:(i-1)];
  yp1lag<-ARBreak[1:(i-2)];
  Left<-lm(yp1~yp1lag);
  LeftRSS<-sum(Left$residuals^{2});
  #Right
  yp2<-ARBreak[(i+2):626];
  yp2lag<-ARBreak[(i+1):625];
  Right<-lm(yp2~yp2lag);
  RightRSS<-sum(Right$residuals^{2});
  #Total
  yptot<-ARBreak[2:626];
  yptotlag<-ARBreak[1:625];
  tot<-lm(yptot~yptotlag);
  totRSS<-sum(tot$residuals^{2});

  #Chow Test 
  Numer<-(totRSS-(RightRSS+LeftRSS))/14;
  Denomer<-(RightRSS+LeftRSS)/(626-14);
  CTest[i]<-Numer/Denomer;
} 

which.max(CTest); #73 so 90 + 73 = 163


#CUSUM test

RegMat <- data.frame(cbind(yp1,yp1lag))
Model <- lm(yp1~yp1lag, data = RegMat)
F_values <- Fstats(Model, from = 0.15, data = RegMat )
plot(F_values$Fstats)
breakpoint <- breakpoints(F_values) # Only one breakpoint found
lines(breakpoints(F_values))
print(breakpoint) #breakpoint is at 409 --> 90 + 409 = 499?
```

Actual results for each test differ (Chow test yields answer of 73+90 = 163 vs. CUSUM test yields answer of 409+90 = 499), but I think I should find the same answer for both.

Comment: What would be helpful for getting an answer is to first edit your code to eliminate everything that is not needed to reproduce the problem and second to provide some data that someone could use to reproduce it.  My first instinct is to say that there wouldn't be two tests if they always gave identical results so I don't think non identical results is the real question. Some data would help to understand the underlying question better.

Comment: Also please say which package you are using since there are numerous packages that include the Chow test.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I used the package "strucchange." I also modified the code above to include the data, sorry about the omission. I'm not sure if there's anything I can remove from the code. You make a good point about the outcome of the two tests - there is a chance that I'm misinterpreting the result of the second test but I'm not sure.

Comment: This isn't my expertise but I have done time series before.  I'm wondering why you wouldn't use the built in sctest.formula() function with the appropriate type options for the comparisons you want to make.  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/strucchange/strucchange.pdf